# How should I scrape all <em> tag innertexts within a <ul> and make them into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape the information I want from a website.

The information that I want is contained within a `ul>li>em`. I have scraped tables before, but I have never scraped lists.

How should I scrape the information I want?

In addition, I want to know if there is a way to make all the innertexts in `<em>` and put them in a `dataframe`.

The `<ul>` basically looks like this.

```
<ul class="reportData">
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>

                   ......

        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select your `<ul>` and use in this case `stripped_strings` to get all text in a list:

```
data = soup.select_one('ul.reportData').stripped_strings
```

or more specific with `list comprehension`from all `em`

```
data = [e.text for e in soup.select('ul.reportData em')]
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<ul class="reportData">
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = soup.select_one('ul.reportData').stripped_strings

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date'])
```

#### Output

| date |
| --- |
| 2015-12-28 |
| 2015-12-28 |
| 2015-12-28 |
| 2015-12-28 |
| 2015-12-28 |

Answer (score 2):

`find_all` returns a list, which you can directly import in pandas:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''<ul class="reportData">
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
        <li><em>2015-12-28</em></li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
df = pd.DataFrame([i.get_text() for i in soup.find('ul', class_='reportData').find_all('em')], columns=['date'])
```